# Unity scriptable object only serializing the unity objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, extending, inspector, scriptable-object

I am trying to make a spell system. My base class for the system looks like this:

```
public abstract class MagicBook : ScriptableObject {
   public Sprite bookSprite;
   public float manaCost;
   public float coolDown;
   public bool rapidFire;

   [HideInInspector] public bool coolDownElapsed;

   public virtual void OnActivate() {

   }

   public virtual void OnActivate(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation) {
    
   }
}
```

Then I have another class extending from MagicBook where I override the OnActivate function. My problem now is that in the inspector only the variable bookSprite is showing and all the other values are not there. I tried adding an [SerializeField] in front of the variables and define them new in the extending class. But they still dont show. Has anyone an idea why they are not showing or how I can fix this?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Please show code for other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create Asset for `ScriptableObject`?
Add attribute to extended class:

```cs
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/NewBook", order = 1)]
```

And then create asset with [image: create asset]

Another idea:
Probably you have custom drawer for this object, but...
Turn your inspector into debug mode and check if properties are visible there.
[image: debug mode]

Cannot reproduce this issue with Unity 2020.1.0f1.

```cs
public class NewBook : MagicBook
{
}
```

[image: Proof]

Comment: It's the first; I'm positive: he/she hasn't instantiated any assets. When you view a ScriptableObject class in the Inspector like a Monobehaviour, only sprite references are serialized.

Comment: It's the first: he/she hasn't instantiated any assets. When you just view a ScriptableObject class in the Inspector like a Monobehaviour, only sprite references are serialized.